# Add greek letter in column header kable and add %-sign in rowname

Tags: tables, greek, knitr, percentage

I had some questions when making a table using kable in Rmarkdown. My output has to be a pdf document, so my header is the following:

```
output: 
   pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex 
    number_sections: true
```

I want to make a table where the column names are equal to γ=1, γ=2 and γ=3. But I do not know how to do it. I have already read that you can use escape=FALSE, but it does not seem to work with a pdf output.

My code is the following right now:

```
rownames(Table1) <- c("Ind 1", "Ind 2", "Ind 3", "Ind 4","Ind 5", "Sum", "Return(%)", "Standard deviation(%)")
colnames(Table1) <- c("\\gamma=2", "\\gamma=3","\\gamma=4")
kable(Table1, caption="Some text", booktabs = T, align = c("l",rep("c",5)), digits=4)  %>%
  kable_styling(position = "center", latex_options = "hold_position") %>%
  column_spec(1, width="10em")  %>%
  footnote(general="Some text",threeparttable = T,footnote_as_chunk = T) # make a table with a note underneath it
```

I know it is possible to do it when I remove the kable_styling and the footnote but these are options I really need. Can someone help me?

Furthermore, I was also wondering if I could put a % sign in my table itself rather than in the row names. Now after 'return' and 'standard deviation' I put the %-sign to indicate all numbers on that row have to be interpreted as percentages, but it would be nicer if I could put a %-sign after each number on these two rows. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify how your query might fall under the purview of TeX.SE.